# Modifying a php script, giving error

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I'm using a wordpress plugin from here:
http://gregorypearcey.com/blog/use-rss-feeds-post-reviews/

I'm trying to modify init.php based on one of the comments, but am getting an error with the mod.

Here is init.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: RSS Reviews
Plugin URI: https://github.com/PearSea/RSS-Reviews
Description: Use this plugin to receive your latest reviews using an RSS feed from sites like TripAdvisor.
Version: 1.2.1
Author: Gregory Pearcey
Author URI: http://gregorypearcey.com/
License: Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*/

//Add the stylesheet into the header
wp_enqueue_style("rss.reviews",WP_PLUGIN_URL."/rss-reviews/css/responsiveslides.css");

//Add the scripts in the footer
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");

wp_enqueue_script(
"rss.reviews", WP_PLUGIN_URL."/rss-reviews/js/responsiveslides.js",
array("jquery"), "1.3.1",1);

wp_enqueue_script(
"rss.reviewssetup", WP_PLUGIN_URL."/rss-reviews/js/rss-reviews.js",
array("jquery","rss.reviews"), "",1);

// Add Widget area
class rss_reviews extends WP_Widget {

// constructor
function rss_reviews() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('RSS Reviews', 'rss_reviews') );
}

// widget form creation
function form($instance) {

// Check values
if( $instance) {
     $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
     $text = esc_attr($instance['text']);
     $amount = esc_textarea($instance['amount']);
} else {
     $title = '';
     $text = '';
     $amount = '';
}
?>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'rss_reviews'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>"><?php _e('RSS Feed URL:', 'rss_reviews'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('amount'); ?>"><?php _e('Amount of Reviews:', 'rss_reviews'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('amount'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('amount'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
</p>
<?php
}

// update widget
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
      $instance = $old_instance;
      // Fields
      $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
      $instance['text'] = strip_tags($new_instance['text']);
      $instance['amount'] = strip_tags($new_instance['amount']);
     return $instance;
}

// display widget front end
function widget($args, $instance) {
   extract( $args );
   // these are the widget options
   $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
   $text = $instance['text'];
   $amount = $instance['amount'];
   echo $before_widget;

   if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {
    // fetch feed items
    $rss = fetch_feed($text);
    if(!is_wp_error($rss)) : // error check
        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity($amount); // number of items
        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
    endif;   

   // Display the widget
   echo '<div id="slider" class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box">';

   // Check if title is set
   if ( $title ) {
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
   }

   echo '<ul class="rslides">';
   if($maxitems == 0) echo '<p>Feed not available.</p>'; // if empty
   else foreach ($rss_items as $item) : 

    echo '<li>'.$item->get_description().'</li>';

    endforeach; 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
} 
   echo $after_widget;
}
}

// register widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("rss_reviews");'));

//Short Code
function rssreviews($atts, $content=null){  

extract(shortcode_atts( array('id' => ''), $atts));  

   if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {
    // fetch feed items
    $rss = fetch_feed($id);
    if(!is_wp_error($rss)) : // error check
        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity($amount); // number of items
        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
    endif;

   if($maxitems == 0){
        return '<p>Feed not available.</p>'; // if empty
   } else {

       $middle = '';
       foreach ($rss_items as $item){ 
           $middle .= '<li>
           <a href="'.$item->get_permalink().'"title="'.$item->get_date('j F Y @ g:i a').'"><h3>'.$item->get_title().'</h3></a>'
           .$item->get_description().'</li><hr>';
        }
        $returnfeed = '<ul class="nobullets">'.$middle.'</ul>';
    return $returnfeed;              
   }

}  

}  
add_shortcode('rssreviews', 'rssreviews');


?>
```

I replaced line 107 as follows:

```
   else foreach ($rss_items as $item) :
```

to

```
   else foreach ($string = $item->get_description();
$search_five = '5 or 5 stars';
$five_reviews = strpos($string, $search_five);
$search_four = '4 or 5 stars';
$four_reviews = strpos($string, $search_four);
if ($five_reviews !== false || $four_reviews !== false ) {
echo ''.$string.'';) :
```

But this gives me an error, unexpected ";" at line 107. Any helpful hints in what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: no, it's the foreach which should have an extra closing bracket, and no semicolon. But still, IMO the OP shouldn't use these shortcut forms, they're very bad style. Rather I would suggest actually simply using nice curly bracers :)

Comment: @Tularis yes i noticed that too ;) his foreach is not correct at all

Comment: Where do you close the last if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not replace the code (lines 106-111) with something like:

```
if($maxitems == 0) {
   echo '<p>Feed not available.</p>'; // if empty
} else {  
   foreach($rss_items as $item) {
      $string = $item->get_description();
      $search_five = '5 or 5 stars';
      $five_reviews = strpos($string, $search_five);
      $search_four = '4 or 5 stars';
      $four_reviews = strpos($string, $search_four);
      if ($five_reviews !== false || $four_reviews !== false ) {
         echo $string;
      }
   }
}
```

This code uses the regular if and foreach syntax (making it much more readable) and removes the additional foreach on the `$item` which I don't think you actually needed (since `$item->getDescription()` returns a `string`, not an `array` or `object`).

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Perfect!

Here is what I ended up using:
        if($maxitems == 0) {
    echo '<p>Feed not available.</p>'; // if empty
    } else {  
      foreach($rss_items as $item) {
      $string = $item->get_description();
      $search_five = '5 or 5 stars';
      $five_reviews = strpos($string, $search_five);
      $search_four = '4 or 5 stars';
      $four_reviews = strpos($string, $search_four);
      if ($five_reviews !== true || $four_reviews !== true ) {
         echo '<li>'.$string.'</li>';
      }
      }
      }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    foreach ($string = $item->get_description()) :
        $search_five = '5 or 5 stars';
        $five_reviews = strpos($string, $search_five);
        $search_four = '4 or 5 stars';
        $four_reviews = strpos($string, $search_four);

        if ($five_reviews !== false || $four_reviews !== false ) {
            echo ''.$string.''; 
        } 
    endforeach;
```

Or this way preferably:

```
    foreach ($string = $item->get_description()) {
        $search_five = '5 or 5 stars';
        $five_reviews = strpos($string, $search_five);
        $search_four = '4 or 5 stars';
        $four_reviews = strpos($string, $search_four);

        if ($five_reviews !== false || $four_reviews !== false ) {
            echo ''.$string.''; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: It's giving me an error for both. Thanks anyway! I got the answer form the other user.